# Need some assistance with fpdf positioning

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm new to fpdf cell and multicell and I need help with my code. Below is the code I've written:

```
$pdf->Cell(60, 6, 'MAILING ADDRESS', 'L,R', 0);
$pdf->Multicell(65, 5, $puchaser1[0]["address"], 1);
$pdf->Cell(60, 11, $puchaser2[0]["address"], 1);

$pdf->Cell(60, 8, 'PHONE NUMBER', 1, 0);
$pdf->Cell(65, 8, $puchaser1[0]["contact_no"], 1, 0);
$pdf->Cell(65, 8, $puchaser2[0]["contact_no"], 1, 1);
```

[image: a look at the problem]

I want to make it look like this:
[image: expected output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and errors as text and not as images.

Comment: The script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3) can help

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using more variables. Your code could look like this:

```
// Height is different in multicell, this stands for lineheight and should be the same as other cells :)
// I would advise you to go for, SMALL_CELL and BIG_CELL if you want to differentiate
$WIDTH_CELL = 60;
$HEIGHT_CELL = 5;

// Most of the time, you want to border all so let's put this in a variable as well 
// Not in your case though, but more on that below this :)
$BORDER = 1;

$pdf->Cell($WIDTH_CELL, $HEIGHT_CELL, 'MAILING ADDRESS', $border, 0);
$pdf->Multicell($WIDTH_CELL, $HEIGHT_CELL, $puchaser1[0]["address"], $border);
$pdf->Cell($WIDTH_CELL, $HEIGHT_CELL, $puchaser2[0]["address"], $border);

$pdf->Cell($WIDTH_CELL, $HEIGHT_CELL, 'PHONE NUMBER', 1, 0);
$pdf->Cell($WIDTH_CELL, $HEIGHT_CELL, $puchaser1[0]["contact_no"], $border, 0);
$pdf->Cell($WIDTH_CELL, $HEIGHT_CELL, $puchaser2[0]["contact_no"], $border, 1);
```

However this does **NOT** resolve your problem. And your going to have a bad time because you will need to:

1. Keep track of your starting Y
2. Save your Y value after adding the multicell
3. Use these two values to draw a rectangle for the entire row

All other borders should be specific as 'L','R' or 'LR'. You will have to drawn the top borders, bottom (and sometimes L or R) borders with the rectangles.

It's a lot of code so I will help you further if you have something like this :)